# Non-trivial groups pairwise non-isomorphic with isomorphic direct products

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Are there four non-trivial groups $G_1,G_2,H_1,H_2$ pairwise non-isomorphic but such that $G_1 \times G_2$ is isomorphic to $H_1 \times H_2$?

My idea was to consider the abelian groups and something related to their decomposition as direct product of cyclic groups, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try again with abelian groups of the form $C_2^k = C_2 \times C_2 \times \cdots \times C_2$ with $k$ direct factors. It's easy.

Comment: What do you mean for $C_2^k$?

Comment: $C_2$ meaning $Z/2Z$. Can use small finite products.

Comment: I think the minimal $\;k\;$ for this to fully work is $\;k=5\;$ ...

Comment: @TheWanderer: Hint: 2 + 3 = 1 + 4

Comment: I'm sorry, but if I take $C_2^2 \times C_2^3$ and $C_2 \times C_2^4$, the first group has not an element of order $4$, while the second has it. How are they isomorphic?

Comment: @TheWanderer Nobody in those groups you wrote has an order greater than two...

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I confused the notation $C_2^4$ with $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C_n$ denote the cyclic group with $n$ elements.

Relevant fact: If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, then $C_a \times C_b = C_{ab}$.

Idea of proof of fact (or look in any group theory book): It suffices to show that $C_{ab}$ is cyclic - i.e. is generated by a single element. The naive guess is $(1,1)$. Observe that $a*(1,1) = (0,a)$, and since $a$ is a unit modulo $b$ (this is equivalent to them being relatively prime), there is some c so that $ca*(1,1) = (0,1)$. Similarly you can get $(1,0)$ as a mutliple of $(1,1)$.

Do you see how to use this fact?

There are other ways also, such as what is being suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more fun if we were to insist that $G_{1}\simeq G_{2}$ and $H_{1}\simeq H_2$ and then give a counterexample.

Tony Corner's example of an abelian group $A\not\simeq A\oplus A$ but with $A\simeq A\oplus A\oplus A$  will give an example. Take $B=A\oplus A$ and then
$$
A\oplus A\simeq A\oplus (A\oplus A\oplus A)\simeq (A\oplus A)\oplus (A\oplus A)\simeq B\oplus B
$$

(For the group $A$ see MR0169905 Corner, A.L.S., On a conjecture of Pierce concerning direct decomposition of Abelian groups. 1964 Proc. Colloq. Abelian Groups (Tihany, 1963) pp.43--48 Akademiai Kiado, Budapest.)